# Jquery UI sortable прыгают элементы

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap, javascript

Добрый день
Использую на сайта bootsrap fluid layout+jquery sortable
Все хорошо, но при передвигании, другие элементы прыгают и я никак не пойму в чем дело.
Код + демо можно глянуть тут: http://jsfiddle.net/6UkdR/3/
Уже второй день мучаюсь, буду рад любой подсказке.

Comment: Уберите  `margin-top:10px`; у `.thumbnail`.

Comment: не помогает

Comment: да, смотрел в 12 опере, там все не так как вы вероятно хотели изначально. проблема с бутстрапом, для ui-sortable-placeholder не такие отступы какие должны быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.row-fluid [class*="span"]` там `margin-left: 2.7624309392265194%;` когда убираешь галочку он отскакивает влево (через `Chrome` правой кнопкой Просмотр кода). На то же расстояние что и при перетаскивании. Может быть оно?

Comment: не знаю. убирал, действительно отскакивает, но потом при клике все-равно еще отскакивает